# How to ignore cache when loading html in chromiumwebbrowser?

Tags: cefsharp

I make chromiumwebbrowser in c# winform and load html in browser.

In my case, I import js in html but it doesn't work properly.

However, it works if I set disable cache in devtools and reload it.

So, I want to implement disable cache programmatically.
[image]

I tried this code but it failed.

```
public ChromiumWebBrowser chromiumBrowser;

settings = new CefSettings();
settings.CachePath = null;
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add ("disable-application-cache", "1");
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-session-storage", "1");
Cef.Initialize(settings);

Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager().DeleteCookies("", "");
chromiumBrowser.Load(url);
```

And I don't know if I can use the one in this url, and I don't know the specific usage.

https://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_Reload_1.htm

Comment: What have you tried? The API doc is version specific,  you are referencing a very old version see http://cefsharp.github.io/api/ for index of versions. Just call the Reload extension method like you would any other making sure you include a using statement to the namespace the method exists in or call it as any other static method.

Comment: thanks.
I found my version of reload in the url and I will test it. It seems to be possible to ignore the cache via a boolean value in reload.

Comment: Yes you can perform a reload ignoring cache. You could also add request headers to ignore caching or programatically execute DevTools commands I'm guessing https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-setCacheDisabled is the correct command,  see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3158

Comment: thanks. Not sure, but my cefsharp version is 75.1 so it doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: You'll have to upgrade to use DevTools

Comment: Okay. I can't think of a way to solve the problem without an upgrade.